# xcode librarby not found for -IRCTNetwork

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have react native project that I'm trying to run with xcode.
when i run it shows me the error

```
    ld: library not found for -lRCTNetwork
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

actually, i don't know what is -RCTNetwork,
it's not any plugin I installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because you haven't added or linked the network library to your Build Phases in Xcode.

Drag the file, **RCTNetwork.xcodeproj** from `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/`
to the libraries file in Xcode.

Then click on *Build Phases* on the top right-hand corner in Xcode.

Click the drop down of Link Binary With Libraries, then the + sign to add the **libRCTNetwork.a**

Run the build and restart your emulator or device.

Comment: you mean to import the RCTNetwork.xcodepro under build-phases?

Comment: hey @Andrel, i have same issue but now with branch-io, can you please check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433459/react-native-xcode-library-not-found-for-lbranch-sdk

Comment: Additionally, if you're using CocoaPods, you can add RCTNetwork to your Podfile in the React subspecs, then run `pod install`. I personally find it cleaner and easier to manage such dependencies.