# react native xcode library not found for -lBranch-SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have react native v0.49.
After installing react-native-branch with this link
[link to react-native-branch](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking), I try to run with xcode and I get the error

```
ld: library not found for -lBranch-SDK
```

in addition,when I run react-native-link I get

```
react-native-branch ERR! Failed to add file to project
```

Answer (score 6):

Go in **Xcode** > **Targets** > *Your App* > **Build Phases** > **Link Binary With Library**.
Select `libBranch-SDK.a` then click on the **-** *(minus sign)* at the bottom of the list.

Comment: You're a life saver!

Comment: I've just had the same issue with GestureHander, thank you.  As someone new to mobile development and Xcode, i'm a little confused as to why this solution works, and indeed how this problem may have come about?

Comment: Do you know how to perform this linking on the CLI via `xcodebuild`?