# Library not found for -lRNFirebase React Native

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Xcode is giving me an Error:

[image: xcode error library not found -RNFirebase]

I am using React Native Firebase, I have followed the instructions on there site, and I appear to have everything there, but Im not that familiar with Xcode, so I can exactly see the problem.
I have posted more screenshots below:

[image: Libraries]

[image]

**PodFile:**

[image: Podfile]

**Edit:**
[image]

Any Help will be much appreciated

Comment: `Project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> Add -lRNFirebase`

Comment: Hi @PritishVaidya, that you for your very quick response, when I click the + in Link Binary with Libraries, there is no option to add lRNFirebase

Comment: Then re-add Firebase xcodeproj file in the Libraries from its node_module

Comment: After re adding Firebase xcodeproj file, Im now getting a new Error that I have added into my question, if you wouldnt mind taking a look at

Comment: Not sure, but try updating podspec to these versions as mentioned [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1610#issuecomment-441218187)

Comment: I tried updating the pods to latest versions, but still no joy. Im going to try and uninstall the RNFirebase library from my react native project, do you know what the proper way is to uninstall a library, from react native and ios

Comment: @AndrewIrwin Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Hi @dentemm, Sorry no I didnt find a solution, unfortunately. What I ended up doing was creating my App using Expo instead, as Expo doesnt require you to use xcode or Android Studio, so then I was just able to use firebase web sdk in Expo, and then didnt have any problems with expo and firebase. So far so good, its fantastic not having to worry about xcode any more, it was giving me a lot of hasle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native xcode library not found for -lBranch-SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433459/react-native-xcode-library-not-found-for-lbranch-sdk)

Answer (score 3):

This practice solved my problem

Go to your project

1. Select your target
2. General Tab
3. Frameworks, libraries, and embedded content
4. Remove LNRFirebase from the list

Hope it helps