# Invariant Violation: Native component for "RCTImageView" does not exist

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native

I created native project with one 'main' page in Xcode, rest of the project I would like to finish in React Native. Everything went great until I tried to use `<Image>` tag in JSX. I tried to find solution, but without effects.

If I create the project fully in React Native (without existing part in Xcode) `<Image>` tag works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: check a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159026/xcode-librarby-not-found-for-irctnetwork/47163258#47163258

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out where was the problem located. 
I hadn't added 'RCTImage' to my Podfile

```
    pod 'React', :path => './node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge', 
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTImage', // <- this component was missing
  ]
```

Comment: if i dont use pod? is there any solution for that, thanks